# Store values and output a csv file

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

I'm new to C# and WPF. I will need to write a program to collect and display RS232 data and save it as a CSV file. Do I need database or XML? Is there any relevant tutorial anyone could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Around the storage..**

Do you want to sort / filter / search the data?
Then I would store it in a SQL Database and export it later on to CSV (using a simple StringWriter).

If you don't want to access the data, just collect it and put it into CSV I would simply write it to CSV as the data comes in.

For **reading CSV** I would recommend using a LINQ to CSV implementation.

E.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx 
or http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I use SQL database, would that mean other user who use the software also required to have SQL 2008 database installed?

Comment: Either that or have network access to the machine.. (via a webservice).

Comment: There are more databases than just SQL 2008. SQL stands for Structured Query Language - and merely relates to a common way of querying databases. It's supported by the vast majority of database systems.

Comment: I'm going for a stand-alone application where user won't need to install database. Shall I still use LINQ?

Comment: Also, I would also need to display real-time graphing and statistical analysis - could that be done without using a database?

Comment: I would go for a database. Either Microsoft SQL 2008 or SqlLite or Microsoft SqlCE (the last two ones don't require an installation).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about RS232, but I gather this is binary data coming off a serial port?

I would question the whole idea of outputing it as a CSV file - text based formats are not ideal for this.

XML is a better choice - you could use Base64 to sort out the encoding issues, and you could structure your document sensibly to meet your purposes.

Another idea, depending on what you're trying to do, might be to use a file based Database. I don't mean MS Access either (Spit!) - look up SQLite.

If someone is really forcing you down a CSV route for binary data, then I suggest you and they need to have a talk about whether this really is, when it comes down to it, really such a great idea.

Comment: I looking for a solution where the user, after installing the software, won't need to install the database. So I'm going for a stand-alone application.

Comment: Lookup SQLite - it's what you're looking for. You just ship their dll and you're laughing!